# pass char array as argument

Tags: c, function, pointers

Can anyone explain to me what I don't understand here please?

I am trying to pass the argument as a "string" (i know there are no strings in c) so that I can use that string later with other functions like it's a file name that has to be passed for example.
But I don't know why it won't accept it or what type should it be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char *array= argv[0];
    foo(*array);
}

void foo( char *array) 
// notice the return type - it's a pointer
{
    printf(array);
}
```

thanks alot!

Comment: you dereference array while passing it to foo. So you only pass the very first byte value if it is a c string literal

Comment: You should avoird expression such as `printf(s)` because it's an uncontrolled format string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be calling the function like this:

```
foo(array);
```

What you're doing is dereferencing the pointer,  which returns a `char`, which is the first character in the string.

Your `printf` call should also look like this:

```
printf("%s", array);
```

Your entire fixed code should look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char *array)
{
    printf("%s", array);
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    // TODO:  make sure argv[1] exists
    char *array= argv[1];
    foo(array);
}
```

Comment: i removed the asterix like you said, it still doesn't work!
It says: redefinition: different basic types

Comment: i did both fixes, still says same thing and won't compile!

Comment: @Ryan:  Specifically, what error message are you getting from your compiler?

Comment: 'foo':redefinition; different basic types

Comment: that excatly with the first line of the function as the location of the error

Comment: the entire fixed code won't compile, would it compile with you? thanks!

Comment: @Ryan, It compiles fine one ideone. The only difference is that wants a `return 0;` for runtime and you can't give it `argv[1]`. It works fine if that's changed to a string literal, though.

Comment: thank you so much for all your time and effort, i really appreciate it, it works!! :) thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 5):

When you say `foo (*array)`, you're decaying the array into a pointer to the first element, in order to dereference that element, giving you the first character. That's what you're trying to pass to the function. Leave out the asterisk and just pass `array` for it to decay into the pointer you need.

The other issue is that you're not using `printf` correctly. First of all, here's a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). You need to pass a string of tokens that tell the compiler what type of argument to expect next because it has no way of telling. In your case, your string would contain `"%s"` to tell it to expect a `char *`, and then you'd pass `array` as that `char *` argument.

```
printf ("The string is %s", array);
```

Comment: i removed the asterix like you said, it still doesn't work! It says: redefinition: different basic types

Comment: i noticed you reedited to how it was before? Shall there be an asterix in the argument being passed to the function or not? Actually i just noticed with or without it, it won't work

Comment: @Ryan, You shouldn't be dereferencing the decayed array anywhere. It's already decayed into the pointer you need when it gets passed into a function.

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is a array of character pointers, that means `argv` is going to store the address of all the strings which you passed as command line argument.

so `argv[0]` will gives you the address of first string which you passed as command line argument, that you are storing into the pointer variable `array` in `main` function.

Now you have to pass only the address to the function `foo` but you are passing the first character of that string. For example if your first command line argument is `temp.txt` you are passing character `t` to the function `foo`. So inside `foo` function you are having a char pointer variable `array`, in that ASCII value of the character `t` will be assigned. And then you are passing that to `printf`, which will treads that ASCII value as address, and it will tries to access that address to print which will leads to crash (unexpected behaviour).

So you have to pass only the address of the command line argument to the function `foo` like below.

`foo(array);`

`printf(array)` - Here `printf` will treads the format specifier as string(`%s`) and it will tries to print all the characters starting from the address `array` untill it meets a null character `\0`.

But better to add the `printf` like below

`printf("%s", array);`